# Format String with fixed length with leading spaces

Tags: vb6, formatting, format, number-formatting

I need to format a string for a fixed length. 
I tried to use this format function from [msdn](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiD4vaa7PXQAhXFiRoKHTNsC-0QFggfMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fde-de%2Flibrary%2Fwb216dct(v%3Dvs.90).aspx&usg=AFQjCNGDEgPTqzwxVhADPUwELvuhXTWRvA&sig2=GrMA2ji5-7LnRd9YtIzVGQ&cad=rjt)

```
Dim i as Decimal
i = 123,12
MsgBox(Format(i,"######.##"))
```

> Output 123.12

But the Output I want is with the leading spaces. ( the underscore should be a space char )

> Output ___123.12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the spaces in the format syntax like this and it'll work.

```
Format(12.323, "  ##.##")
```

Comment: well, this was to easy to get it :D  . Thank you, worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Before the arrival of `Format`, the canonical way to do this was:

```
Result$ = Right$(Space$(9) & Incoming$, 9)
```

...which you can generalize by replacing "9" with a variable.

This works for leading zeroes as well, using `String$("0", n)` instead of `Space$(n)`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the Rset command?

x = (Format$(123.5, "$##0.00"))

Print "x" & x & "x"

RSet x = (Format$(1.5, "$##0.00"))

Print "x" & x & "x"

Output :

x$123.50x

x  $1.50x

Comment: `Dim test As String
RSet test = Format(123.45, "$#####0.00")` 

output = $123.45 - without the leeding spaces.

Answer (score -2):

string s = "String goes here";

string line1 = String.Format("{0,27}", s);

string line2 = String.Format("{0,-27}", String.Format("{0," + ((27 + s.Length) / 2).ToString() +  "}", s));

string line3 = String.Format("{0,-27}", s);

Comment: this is not vb6 code, or ? 
{0,27} as format definition is not working / the returned string is "{0,27}", not the formated input, if I try to use it.